# Should I be using EF6 from a SQL CLR Function

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sqlclr

I've been tasked with researching taking some complex calculation code (in C#) and moving it into a CLR function on SQL Server 2012.  The complex nature of the calculations mean that writing this as a classic SQL SP or UDF isn't really viable, hence the idea of using CLR - the code exists and is tested.

The problem I have is that the calculations use a data layer which uses EF6.  Obviously I would be extracting as small a portion of the existing code as possible for the CLR function(s) but I still have to fulfil all the dependencies.

My question is not **how** can I do this [that comes later :) ] so much as **should** I do this?  Somehow it feels wrong to be stuffing the whole of EF into the very database that I'm going to be accessing to perform the calculations - it feels very bloated.

Opinions, suggestions, thoughts please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a *very* pressing and specific need to keep the code-base in sync between the app layer and this SQLCLR function, I would say:

No. There does not seem to be much, if any, benefit from doing this. It should like you just need a few data points and those are very easy to grab with a simple `SqlConnection` using `Context Connection = true;` for the connecting string (that is the in-process connection).

And, given that performance is a concern (as it should be anyway, but still) hence the reason for going down this SQLCLR path to begin with, it seems counter-productive to add in the layers and layers of code that allow for the ease-of-use abstraction layer that is the Entity Framework.

Also, why are you grabbing the data from within the function instead of passing it into the function? Are there values that get passed in that require additional lookups based on their particular value? You will gain quite a bit of performance by structuring the scalar function to be deterministic:

1. Scalar SQLCLR functions marked as `IsDeterministic = true` in the `SqlFunction` attribute have their output cached and mapped to the input params so they can be looked-up (within the context of additional rows in the same query) and re-used instead of running the function again, and
2. Scalar SQLCLR functions marked as `IsDeterministic = true`, AND *not* marked `DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read`, in the `SqlFunction` attribute are allowable in parallel plans. If either `IsDeterministic` is *not* marked as `true` or `DataAccess` (or even `SystemDataAccess`) are marked as `Read`, then they will act like regular T-SQL functions in that they will prevent any query that uses them from getting a parallel execution plan.

Comment: The need is that the calculation functionality be accessible both from within SQL Services (other SPs, reporting services, other currently not redeveloped systems) but also from traditional external systems.  Hence the need to encapsulate the code in just one location accessible to both environments.

The code is highly complex, using multiple lookups and data-passes - financial in nature.  Trying to convert the C# to SQL would be a nightmare, besides which we have a currently working mechanism.

Comment: @Mike : Hey. I would say that is critical info that should be in the question :-). Also, what do you mean "encapsulate the code in just one location accessible to both environments"? The SQLCLR code is hosted within SQL Server and cannot be accessed externally, nor will it access something remote (though it can access a COM component registered on the same system). If the calculation is fastest when done in the database, then maybe the central location should be the SQLCLR function ;-).

Comment: @Mike, I hadn't seen your update to your comment when I replied. How are you going to use this SQLCLR function? In a SELECT or WHERE clause (i.e. where it will run per row of the data set for multiple rows)? Or as part of a larger batch of SQL statements that runs once for that batch? I was not saying it would be worthless if it had to do data access, just that there are major benefits to not doing so. But if that isn't possible then oh well. And overall I agree with doing complicated stuff via SQLCLR (hence http://www.SQLsharp.com ;-), just trying to guide you to the best possible outcome :).

Comment: I appreciate your comments mate, no worries.  The idea is that it would be nice to have essentially one dll (ignoring the dependency issue) which contains the calculation which can either be called directly from a .net component but which we can also embed within a CLR function to allow it to be called from within SQL Server - basically we want to have to maintain only one code base for it.  I've slightly simplified the scenario for (I thought) clarity, it is actually a set of functions, some of which return single values and others return datasets.

Comment: @Mike, I don't think it would work out that cleanly. SQLCLR is a very restricted CLR-host environment. I get the desire for a single code-base, really, but I am being realistic here. Given that the `SqlTypes` are slightly different than regular .Net types, you will at least need wrapper methods for SQLCLR that call your existing, common methods. But depending on what those are doing, it might require changes to that common code base. You can't use class-level, static variables. And you may need to import all EF DLLs into SQL Server. It's a different environment and the code should match that.

Comment: @Mike, but I am not saying that you shouldn't try it if you think it will have that benefit and won't run into the issues that I am thinking might be there. After all, I don't really know the specifics of your setup so maybe it could be structured to work. The base concept of a shared-DLL that is deployed to both appserver and SQL Server and is access by DLLs in each environment that provider the appropriate wrappers is fine, it is just the dependency at that lowest level on EF that seems questionable, and leads me to wonder if the code is doing stuff that is normally fine but not in SQLCLR.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion mate.  I'm inclined to agree with you.  This is really just a research task at this stage to see whether it could be done.  I had my doubts due to the "weight" of the code involved and you've confirmed much of my concerns.  Simple case of... just because you can does not necessarily mean you should.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Mike , you are quite welcome. As I said, if the calculations could be abstracted such that the DLL could be common and whether values were supplied via EF or direct calls via Context Connection (almost no connection overhead, if any) was environment-specific, that might work. But check out my answer here from earlier today ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81290/30859 ), specifically the warning: you would face the same issue importing EF DLLs. For more info, check out http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/ (a series I am working on) and/or contact me via http://www.SQLsharp.com/